# if nodejs datebase over 256MB, buffer toSting failed

Tags: node.js, database, v8, nedb

I have a server which running nodejs with [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), everything is fine until the db files reach 256MB, nodejs go down and give me a `buffer toSting failed`.
I do know 256MB is the limit for strings in V8, but I dont suppose nedb wont handle it at all. So what should I do if a db file over 256MB, and how can I repair my db files?

Comment: I guess you got an answer already? https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/issues/363

Comment: @robertklep yes, and this make me cry

Comment: Looking at the file format, it's relatively simple (one JSON document per line), so it should be easy to repair?

Comment: @robertklep No, because I have dataURLs in each line.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific (in your question as well, perhaps: what _exactly_ needs to be repaired?)

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. Actually the db files have no damage, but it is too fat, nedb cannot read it anymore, so the web page down as well. I try to switch to MongoDB asap, but I am still googling how Mongoimport import JSON files.

Comment: Can't you temporarily remove parts of the database so at least you can run the site with a limited amount of data (and in real-only mode)?

Comment: Yes, it running with a backup db. However, client keep posting and it getting overload again, soon...

Comment: Hence the "read-only mode" I mentioned. Better than nothing, and gives you some time to migrate the database.

Comment: thanks. I figure out how MongoImport work, but it limited the file size to 16MB... So whats the point I switch to MongoDB?

Comment: Are you records larger than 16MB? If so, I doubt any database would perform adequately. If you want to store files in your database, you should consider using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) (also part of MongoDB).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep , end up I crop off some old data and made the server run again. I am just wondering how a server run with a large db, such as fb and Google.

Comment: There are plenty of databases that can hold many terabytes of data, MongoDB included.